# rdfa namespace specifically for cars

Tags: rdf, ontology, facebook-opengraph, rdfa, dublin-core

I would like to implement RDFA to a car site.

Triples would go something like:

- This image is about a honda
- This page is about a honda
- This rating is for a honda civic

...etc...

I can't seem to find a namespace to use in my case. For example , I can easily see how the Dublin Core namespace can be used for books (http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/) since it has a "publisher" and "author" term name. But how about cars? Is there a namespace for it?  Or should I simply use a generic namespace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facebook's [OGP](http://ogp.me/) just has a generic 'product'. What's the dictionary of properties you want to store?

Comment: i want to store makes, models, descriptions and images of cars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you come across the [Car Options Ontology](http://www.volkswagen.co.uk/vocabularies/coo/ns) (COO), by Hepp Research GmbH and Volkswagen UK?

> The COO provides a vocabulary for
>   exposing available configuration
>   options for car models. It allows
>   indicating choices that can be made as
>   well as compatibility, dependency, and
>   inclusion information.

COO imports and extends the [GoodRelations ontology](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/), in particular, the [gr:ProductOrServiceModel](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1#ProductOrServiceModel) part, which describes features of a product.

**EDIT:**

COO and Vehicle Sales Ontology (VSO) are designed at the same period of time (by the same person!) for slightly different purposes:

> The Car Options Ontology is designed
>   to be used in combination with
>   GoodRelations for the commercial
>   aspects of offers for sale or rental,
>   and the Vehicle Sales Ontology for car
>   features.

To understand the base GoodRelations ontology better, you may want to take a look at the following paper:

Hepp, Martin: *[GoodRelations: An Ontology for Describing Products and Services Offers on the Web](http://www.heppnetz.de/files/GoodRelationsEKAW2008-crc-final.pdf)*, Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Knowledge Engineering and Knowledge Management (EKAW2008), Acitrezza, Italy, September 29 - October 3, 2008, Springer LNCS, Vol 5268, pp. 332-347.

Answer (score 6):

COO has already been mentioned; another option would be the [Vehicle Sales Ontology](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/vso/ns), which also interoperates with [GoodRelations](http://purl.org/goodrelations/) (and comes from the same research group, in fact). With respect to showing images, [`foaf:depiction`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_depiction) is a generic (it doesn't constrain the domain or range) property,  which is widely used by other RDF-based tools

Comment: Good find! How did I miss that one in the very same page... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Vehicle Sales Ontology, http://purl.org/vso/ns, which is an extension to GoodRelations (http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1.

Here is an example of a car offer:

http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/VSO#RDFa

More recipes:

http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/VSO

Query example:

Scenario: Find car listings for cars with power windows, a mileage lesser or equal to 40,000 miles, and not more than two previous owners.

```
PREFIX vso: <http://purl.org/vso/ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?dealername ?dealerwebpage ?offer ?deeplink ?price ?currency ?vin ?mileage
FROM <http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/vso/examples.rdf>
WHERE
{
?d a gr:BusinessEntity .
OPTIONAL {?d gr:legalName ?dealername }
OPTIONAL {?d foaf:page ?dealerwebpage }
?d gr:offers ?offer .
?offer gr:hasPriceSpecification ?p .
?p gr:hasCurrencyValue ?price .
?p gr:hasCurrency ?currency .

{
 { ?offer gr:includes ?car }
 UNION
 {
  ?offer gr:includesObject ?bundle .
  ?bundle gr:typeOfGood ?car .
 }
}

?car a vso:Automobile .
OPTIONAL { ?car vso:VIN ?vin }
?car vso:feature dbpedia:Power_window .
?car vso:mileageFromOdometer ?m .
?m gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement ?unit .
?unit bif:contains "HM" .
{
 { ?m gr:hasMaxValueFloat ?mileage }
UNION
 { ?m gr:hasValueFloat ?mileage }
}
OPTIONAL { ?offer foaf:page ?deeplink }
OPTIONAL { ?car foaf:page ?deeplink }
?car vso:previousOwners ?o .
?o gr:hasValueInteger ?owners .

FILTER (?mileage <= 40000) .
FILTER (?owners <= 2) .
}
```